# The simplest way to copy sql tables from one database to another?

Tags: sql-server, table, copy

So I have been logged into two different database. I want to copy one table from the first database to the other one with its content. I want to overwrite the content of the destination one (Because I have the same table name but it has just few entries) So what is the simplest way to do it?

PS: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2019 and each database located on different server.

Comment: You can use the Export wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article lists out [three simple ways](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/) to copy data from one table to another. To summarise, you can use the Import/Export Wizard in SSMS to copy data from one table to another. You can use the "Generate Scripts" option to generate a script of schema and data from the source then drop your target table and run the script against your target. Lastly, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to transfer data from one table to another.

For your scenario, the easiest option is the Import/Export Wizard for a one-off transfer. If you want to repeat this transfer, a simple solution would be to create a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) on your target SQL Server connecting to your source SQL Server and use the [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) option.

Comment: I did use Import/Export Wizard  and I worked perfectly. Thanks